Internal requests from client to the api in docker
I would like to find out if it is possible to make requests to the api from the front end app using internal network.
Setup:
I have two containers on the Linux web server. One is react app hosted in Nginx container and the other is the backend hosted in aspnet:8.0 container. They share internal docker network. I also use traefik for reverse proxy.
Expectation:
I would like to make requests to http://my-api:8080/api/endpoint from the frontend app instead of using https://example.com/api/endpoint.
I only have SSL cert for the front end react app. I would like to keep the requests internal.. if that even makes sense.
Additionally:
I also get mixed content error because I try to get data via http from a website that was served over https. But if I enable mixed content I get error that domain cannot be resolved. That makes sense because my browser does not know my-api:8080.
Conclusion
Please help me better understand if my expectations are reasonable. If yes, how can I achieve that?

I don't quite understand what you're asking, but the my-api host is only available to containers on the docker network and your app runs in a browser outside the network. So it can't use that host name.

Also see "Unknown host" error calling containerized backend from frontend which discusses the network setup further.  Docker or otherwise, there is no way to have a "private secure channel" from the end user's browser to your service that can only be used by your application and not by other HTTP clients.
